# Proving non-linear inequality doesn't have a solution [Does it have any positive solutions?]

Tags: inequality, nonlinear-system

I am trying to find if following inequalities have a solutions for $x_i\in \mathbb{R+}$

$x_5(x_2-x_1)>x_0(x_4+x_5)$

$x_0x_3>(x_3+x_4)(x_2-x_1)$

How could I prove if this inequality has a solution or not?
I attempted to reach a contradiction by combining the two in-equations but seems like it is not a straight-forward one.

UPDATE:
Some context where this inequality comes from. This was a calculation based on hedged trading.

$x_0$ is the first buy position size, $x_1$ is the second buy size opened with $x_4$ diff from the first position along with a sell position at that price with size of $x_2$. If price moves down with diff of $x_5$ we should be able to make profit, on the other side if price moves up with diff of $x_3$ from the first opened buy we should also have positive profit. These inequalities come from there.

Comment: I should probably ask (too late!): is this a homework exercise? (It didn't look like one, so I went ahead and posted an answer, but on reflection it would have been better to ask.) Homework exercise or not, can you give some context for the question? Questions posted without context, and without showing efforts towards a solution, are likely to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution, because the inequalities can be rewritten as:
$$
0 < \frac{x_4}{x_5} = \frac{x_4 + x_5}{x_5} - 1 < \frac{x_2 - x_1}{x_0} - 1 < \frac{x_3}{x_3 + x_4} - 1 = -\frac{x_4}{x_3 + x_4} < 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

After multiplying left sides and right sides we have

$$
x_5(x_2-x_1)x_0x_3\gt x_0(x_4+x_5)(x_3+x_4)(x_2-x_1)
$$

or

$$
x_3x_5 \gt (x_4+x_5)(x_3+x_4)
$$

which is false because $x_i\in \mathbb{R+}$